# How to load a function when a controller is called in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, mean-stack, angularjs-routing

I have a function

```
        state('showList', {
            url: '/listView',
            templateUrl: 'app/templates/showlist.html',
            controller: "showListCtrl"
        }).
```

My controller,

```
.controller('overViewCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.getList = function(){
        //A http call
    }
 });
```

When my route changes to '/listView',then the overView controller is called but function getList() is not called but i gets called when i refreshed my page.Can any one please help me.I just want to call that function  the moment the controller gets loaded.Thanks.

When my route changes to '/listview'

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the code inside the function outside ,

```
.controller('overViewCtrl', function ($scope) 
    //put it here without a function 

 });
```

or you can use ng-init on the page to call the function

Comment: If i put there there is an erreor getlist is not a function.

Comment: you dont need to have getlist

Answer (score 0):

```
.controller('overViewCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.getList = function(){
        //A http call
    }
  $scope.getList() //just call it here

 });
```

or I'd recommend that you use `resolve` for getting data initially

https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/advanced-routing-and-resolves-a2fcbf874a1c#.t127bl60d

Answer (score 0):

You can use ui-router's [`resolve`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) function to keep your controller skinnier yet still have access to the resolved data once your controller has loaded

```
// router
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
  resolve: {
    simpleObj: function(){
      return {value: 'simple!'};
    }
  }
}

// controller
['simpleObj', function(simpleObj) {
  console.log(simpleObj); // ==> value: 'simple!'
}]
```